# Buttons at the bottom of the list view in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

I am working on Android application in which I want to fix the button at the bottom of the list, so if the list is refreshed and some more items add to the list so the button should be still at the last of last.

I have used the following code but the problem is that it is showing the button like this image.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/newlistselector"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/newlistselector"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.ziqitza.views.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgNotificationProfile"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSearchContact"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll_indicator"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowright" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_indicator"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/roundcorner_topright_downright"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNotificationDesc"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDateTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Status: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="9sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="9sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgSearchContact"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNotificationTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text="time"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="8sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter and binder code:

```
private AdapterDataBinder<ParseObject> mNotificationsBinder = new AdapterDataBinder<ParseObject>() {



        @Override
        public void bind(ParseObject data, View view, int position) {


            if (isLoadingFirstTime) {
            mHolder.mTxtDesciption = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNotificationDesc);
            mHolder.mTxtTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNotificationTime);
            mHolder.mImageProfile = (CircularImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgNotificationProfile);
            mHolder.mll_State = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_indicator);
            mHolder.mTxtDesciption.setText(data.getString("description"));
            mHolder.txtStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

//          mHolder.btnRequest = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            mHolder.txtStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (!data.getString("type").equals("TrustedNetwork")) {
                showStatus(data);

            } else
                mHolder.txtStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            mHolder.mTxtTime.setText(mSDF.format(data.getCreatedAt()));

            try {

                if (data.getBoolean("seen")) {
                    mHolder.mll_State.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else
                    mHolder.mll_State.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ParseFile userimage = data.getParseObject("sender").getParseFile("profileImage");

                if (userimage == null) {
                    Utils.loadProfileImage(NotificationsActivity.this, null, mHolder.mImageProfile);
                } else
                    Utils.loadProfileImage(NotificationsActivity.this, null, mHolder.mImageProfile);
                Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(userimage.getUrl()).into(mHolder.mImageProfile);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            view.setTag(mHolder);

            }else{

            mHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void bind(ParseObject data, View view) {
        }
    };
```

Holder Class:

```
ViewHolder mHolder = new ViewHolder();

    static class ViewHolder{

        private TextView mTxtDesciption, mTxtTime;
        private CircularImageView mImageProfile;
        Button btn;// = (Button) findView(R.id.refreshBtn);
        private LinearLayout mll_State;
        TextView txtStatus;
        Button btnRequest;
    }
```

Comment: Bottom of the screen and bottom of the list are two different things. What you want ? Buttons at the last (after all items) or at the bottom of the screen ?

Comment: actually you have posted your list_item xml please check below answer i have do it for you

Comment: If you want the the buttons to be always at the bottom of the list, then you can use footer. Maybe see this 
http://android24hours.blogspot.sg/2011/05/android-how-to-add-header-and-footer-to.html

Comment: Just in case, you don't want to a footer you can try this workaround.. Increase the count returned from `getCount()` by 1 > In `getView()` method inflate the button's layout XML for the last `position == getCount()-1`. Although using `Footer` is preferred way ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to place buttons at the bottom of the list items, then you can use the `addFooterView()` method of `ListView`. For instance, this will work for one button added in the footer of the list.

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("Done");
ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourlist);
lst.addFooterView(btn);
// * your view containing the 3 buttons *//
```

This will put the view containing the 3 buttons you mentioned in your image after the last item in the `List`.

Answer (score 1):

do it this way

main_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linTop"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Select All"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing  to my comment..

1. Add Footer - Answer by [Jibran Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30349121/3485152)
2. The `count` workaround

   - Use `BaseAdapter` to inflate data in the `ListView`
   - Update the `getCount()` function to send back incremented length.

     `@Override
     public int getCount() {
         return data.length + 1;
     }`
   - Now, update the `getView()` method to inflate different views based on position.

     `@Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         if(position != getCount() - 1)
             convertView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
         else
             convertView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.button, null);
         return convertView;
     }`
   - Don't forget to add the `ViewHolder` pattern to this code.

To Use `AdapterDataBinder`, I don't have any idea about how the maximum count is decided here, so you yourself have to look for the tweaking as done in `getCount()` but for the code from `getView()` method it should be put inside `onBind()`

```
if (isLoadingFirstTime || position == last - 1) {
    if (position == last - 1) {
        // Inflate the buttons layout
    } else {
        // Do as you already did...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please check my edited question. I have put some more code for binder and holder class. Can you please help me out to put the above logic in it. Because i cant figure it out.

Comment: Sorry but no idea about `AdapterDataBinder`, but as per the looks of it.. I have updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the solution, i am now passing my `ViewGroup` in `LayoutInflater` in which i contained the layout of my footer and then in my `ViewGroup` i am passing my button and finally i am adding footer view in my list view.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, mListView, false);

 mListView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);
 mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 final Button footerRefreshBtn = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.footerRefreshBtn);

 footerRefreshBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 footerRefreshBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 populateNotifications(10);
 }
                    });
```